# To get the child nodes of a parent node in an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

my xml file goes like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<raml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="raml21.xsd">
<cmData type="actual" scope="all" name="plan_file">
<header>
 <log dateTime="2011-05-18T04:05:02" action="created" /> 
</header>
<managedObject class="SAAL" distName="FGW-74/HNBGW-1/SAAL-1" operation="update">
 <p name="SigN1">100</p> 
 <p name="MaxCc">4</p> 
 <p name="MaxPd">99</p> 
 <p name="MaxStat">67</p> 
 <p name="TimerCc">200</p> 
 <p name="TimerIdle">100</p> 
 <p name="TimerKeepAlive">100</p> 
 <p name="TimerNoResponse">1500</p> 
 <p name="TimerPoll">100</p> 
</managedObject>
</cmData>
</raml>
```

i need to get all the child nodes under the class 'SAAL' to another array. 
i am using python version 3.

thanks for ur help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [elementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module or one of it's derivatives for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<raml ...
</raml>''')
child_nodes = root.findall('.//*[@class="SAAL"]/*')
print(child_nodes)
```

---

```
[<Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01C78>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01CC8>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01D18>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01D68>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01DB8>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01E08>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01E58>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01EA8>,
 <Element 'p' at 0x0000000002B01EF8>]
```

Comment: i need to display the child nodes as such not the positions.

Comment: @user2667397, I don't understand what you mean.